# Why does changing inertial frames lower your proper time?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, acceleration, inertial-frames

The twin paradox is resolved as the twin who moves through at least two inertial frames has a shorter worldline (therefore less time elapsed in their frame) than the twin who remains in one. I know the crucial aspect is the *multiple frames* not the acceleration, since you can have [variations of the twin paradox with no acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_paradox#Role_of_acceleration).

Besides calculating the proper time for each twin's path, **is there a (perhaps more intuitive) reason that changing inertial frames will lower the time elapsed on your watch?**

Comment: From the twin on the rocket's perspective everything moves with some speed v. Therefore, by length contraction, it sees the universe contracted. Therefore, from the twin's perspective, he/she travels less distance compared to the stationary one on Earth.

Comment: You say multiple frames is the crucial aspect rather than acceleration, but I don't see how you can move through multiple different inertial frames without accelerating. So it seems to me that acceleration is the crucial aspect.

Comment: The "triplet" paradox has the multiple inertial frames without acceleration. The acceleration only serves to break the symmetry, but there are other methods to break the symmetry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bear in mind that switching from one reference frame to another does not in itself make any difference to the time on your watch. If you perform an instantaneous switch at 12:00 you watch will still show 12:00. The reason why it makes a difference in the twin paradox is because shifting to a new reference frame tilts your time axis in spacetime. The tilting of your time axis also tilts your 'planes of simultaneity', since these are orthogonal to your time axis. The direction of the tilt in your plane of simultaneity is upwards in your direction of travel (relative, that is, to the orientation of your planes of simultaneity in the frame you have just left).

Imagine you are some distance from Earth and stationary relative to the Earth. Your time axis will be parallel to the time axis of the Earth (since you and the Earth are in the same frame of reference) which means that you and the Earth share common planes of simultaneity. If the time is half past three on a Thursday afternoon on Earth, it its also half past three on Thursday afternoon where you are, assuming you adopt Earth time locally. If you suddenly switch to a new reference frame by moving towards the Earth, your plane of simultaneity tilts upwards in the direction you are heading, so if you ask what time is it 'now' on Earth, the answer will  no longer be half-past three on Thursday but instead it will be some later date/time, the difference depending on how quickly you are moving relative to the Earth (which determines the angle of tilt) and how far away you are (since two tilted planes diverge more and more the further you go from the point at which they intersect). By you tilting your plane of simultaneity, the time you consider to be 'now' back on Earth jumps forward, and it is that jump that accounts for the extra ageing of the Earth by the time you return to it.

Answer (score 7):

> Besides calculating the proper time for each twin's path, is there a (perhaps more intuitive) reason that changing inertial frames will lower the time elapsed on your watch?

Yes. This is basically the triangle inequality. In Euclidean geometry lengths are given by $ds^2 = dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2$. This metric results in the fact that the shortest path between two points is a straight line.

In Minkowski (or Lorentzian) geometry, lengths are given by $ds^2 = -c^2 dt^2 + dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2$. This metric results in the fact that the longest path between two points is a straight line. At least for the paths that massive objects can take.

So the elapsed time on a watch, called proper time, is just the length of your path through spacetime. That length is longest for a straight path because of the - sign in the metric.

Answer (score 3):

All inertial frames are equivalent. That means you can use any inertial frame to solve any problem. You are not obliged to use a particular frame ("rest frame" or not).

With respect to *any* inertial frame, the spacetime path of the stay-at-home twin is straight, and that of the travelling twin is bent. Even in the accelerationless version where the traveling twin uses two different clocks, the spacetime path along which the time is supposed to be measured is bent. As Dale's answer says, the triangle inequality is backwards in special relativity: a straight line is the longest worldline between two events, so the stay-at-home twin ages more.

If you split the problem into three pieces (stay-at-home twin, outgoing traveling twin, returning traveling twin) and calculate the time of each piece using a different inertial frame, you will still get the same answer—again, *no matter which three frames you use*. They don't have to be rest frames. But there's no reason to use three frames (rest frames or not) because one is enough.